# Chat user avatars flickering in the "users in this room" area in Firefox

Tags: bug, chat, firefox, profile-picture

Other users have reported this happens to them on Firefox too (zoom in if you can't see it at 100%):

[image]

Roughly every 9 seconds the user avatars "flicker" as if they haven't been fully rendered to the specified size. It makes me think of when a big pic is loading slowly and when it loads fully, the whole image is re-rendered to fit the screen, making the crispy pixels much smoother. I suspect they actually are being re-rendered as part of some animation function.

I'm not sure what's causing it since I don't have any of that webdev experience, but something tells me that the code for "user joins/leaves" animation is responsible. This might be on Windows only.

Comment: Alas, I can't reproduce this on Firefox 32 / XUbuntu Linux.